# BigQuery doesn't recognize partitioned table predicate

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table in BigQuery on a `timestamp` column and I am looking to pull all events that happened in last 96 hours.

```
WITH events AS (
SELECT
    concat(module, '_', replace(lower(action), ' ', '_')) type,
    detail,
    cast(IF(id=0, null, id) as string) id,
    timestamp,
    userId,
    pageName,
FROM fe.logs l
WHERE l.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 96 HOUR)
   AND devicetype in ('desktop', 'mobile', 'tablet')
   AND osname in ('Windows', 'Android', 'Mac OS', 'iOS'))
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(e) payload
from events e
```

But I keep getting

```
Cannot query over table 'fe.logs' without a filter over column(s) 'timestamp' that can be used for partition elimination
```

I thought that 
`WHERE l.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 96 HOUR)` would qualify as a valid filter over partitioned column.

For the sake of completeness I've removed some column names and WHERE conditions from the query, but neither touch the `timestamp` column so I don't think they matter here.

E: actually I omitted (and now added) another part from the original query that convert all rows to JSONs to make it as complete as possible.

Is there some specific operator or syntax for this?

Comment: Can you add a constraint of `AND DATE(l.timestamp) >= DATE(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 96 HOUR))` and see if it makes it work?

Comment: See the directions here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#isolate_the_partition_column_in_your_filter .  You will want to add the 96-hour logic to the left hand side including the partitioned field.

Comment: What you need is some sort of scripting - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862855/132438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when shortening the code for this question, I've left out the part containing the bug. Doing

```
WHERE l.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 96 HOUR)
      AND predicate2
      OR predicate3
```

is not valid.

The full code was

```
WITH events AS (
  SELECT
        concat(module, '_', replace(lower(action), ' ', '_')) type,
        detail,
        cast(IF(id=0, null, id) as string) id,
        timestamp,
        userId,
        pageName,
  FROM  fe.logs l
  WHERE l.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 96 HOUR)
        AND devicetype in ('desktop', 'mobile', 'tablet')
        AND osname in ('Windows', 'Android', 'Mac OS', 'iOS')
        AND (module='bar' AND action='qux')
        OR (module='foo' AND action='baz') -- bug is here
)
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(e) payload
from events e
```

In the original code I've messed up the brackets and it should have been

```
  WHERE l.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 96 HOUR)
        AND devicetype in ('desktop', 'mobile', 'tablet')
        AND osname in ('Windows', 'Android', 'Mac OS', 'iOS')
        AND ((module='bar' AND action='qux')
          OR (module='foo' AND action='baz'))
```